# Jq tsv error in formatting an array/object

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

I have json file that I am able to loop and get the desired values with the below command. I am trying to gain some insights in displaying these values into a table format. I am using `@tsv` but getting an error `object ({"release":...) cannot be tsv-formatted, only array`. How can I get the below output display?

My desired output is shown below:

```
Release         Installed    Latest    Old      Deprecated
-------         ---------    ------    ---      ----------
test-app        1.0.0        2.0.0     true     false
```

jq:

```
cat test.json | jq '.test[] | select((.outdated or .deprecated) and ((.release|startswith("update")) | not) and ((.release|startswith("upgrade")) | not))'
```

json:

```
{
    "test": [{
        "release": "myapp1",
        "Installed": {
            "version": "0.3.0",
            "appVersion": "v1.2.6"
        },
        "Latest": {
            "version": "",
            "appVersion": ""
        },
        "outdated": false,
        "deprecated": false
    }, {
        "release": "myapp2",
        "Installed": {
            "version": "6.5.13",
            "appVersion": "1.9.1"
        },
        "Latest": {
            "version": "",
            "appVersion": ""
        },
        "outdated": false,
        "deprecated": false
    }, {
        "release": "test-app",
        "Installed": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "appVersion": ""
        },
        "Latest": {
            "version": "2.0.0",
            "appVersion": ""
        },
        "outdated": true,
        "deprecated": false
    }, {
        "release": "update-app",
        "Installed": {
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "appVersion": ""
        },
        "Latest": {
            "version": "3.0.0",
            "appVersion": ""
        },
        "outdated": true,
        "deprecated": false
    }, {
        "release": "upgrade-app",
        "Installed": {
            "version": "2.0.0",
            "appVersion": ""
        },
        "Latest": {
            "version": "2.0.0",
            "appVersion": ""
        },
        "outdated": false,
        "deprecated": true
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `@csv` and `@tsv` expect an array as input, so you could just append the following to your jq filter:

```
| [.release, .Installed.version, .Latest.version, .outdated, .deprecated]
| @tsv
```

Comment: Nice! I did `cat test.json | jq '.test[] | select((.outdated or .deprecated) and ((.release|startswith("update")) | not) and ((.release|startswith("upgrade")) | not)) | [.release, .Installed.version, .Latest.version, .outdated, .deprecated] | @tsv'` and get this result `test-app\t1.0.0\t2.0.0\ttrue\tfalse`. Whats the proper way to add headers?

Comment: I followed up with another questions about empty values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66603976/jq-handling-empty-strings-and-replacing-them-with-a-default-value