# Jq tsv - create headers from keys

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am trying to get jq to render a json object into tsv format. I came across a way to generate headers dynamically using the key name.

I am getting this error:

> object ({"version":...) is not valid in a csv row

I am guessing this is due to some fields being arrays: `Installed` and `Latest`. How can I make this work with those fields? Also, why is my output including `\t`?

Current Output:

```
"RELEASE\tINSTALLED\tLATEST\tOUTDATED\tDEPRECATED"
jq: error (at <stdin>:28): object ({"version":...) is not valid in a csv row
```

Desired output:

```
RELEASE         INSTALLED    LATEST    OUTDATED      DEPRACATED
test-app        1.0.0        2.0.0     true          false    
test-app2       3.0.0        3.5.0     true          false
```

jq

```
cat test1.json | jq '[.[]| with_entries( .key |= ascii_upcase ) ] | (.[0] |keys_unsorted | @tsv), (.[]|.|map(.) |@tsv)'
```

json:

```
[
  {
    "release": "test-app",
    "Installed": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "appVersion": ""
    },
    "Latest": {
      "version": "2.0.0",
      "appVersion": ""
    },
    "outdated": true,
    "deprecated": false
  },
  {
    "release": "test-app2",
    "Installed": {
      "version": "3.0.0",
      "appVersion": ""
    },
    "Latest": {
      "version": "3.5.0",
      "appVersion": ""
    },
    "outdated": true,
    "deprecated": false
  }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing is to get your ducks in a row:

```
map({release, installed: .Installed.version, latest: .Latest.version, deprecated})
```

Now the headers are easy:

```
( .[0] | keys_unsorted | map(ascii_upcase))
```

... and it's safe to use .[] to fetch the values:

```
.[] | [.[]]
```

Putting it all together:

```
map({release, installed: .Installed.version, latest: .Latest.version, deprecated})
| ( .[0] | keys_unsorted | map(ascii_upcase)),
  (.[] | [.[]])
| @tsv
```

#### A line of dashes under the headers

In your related question at [Jq tsv error in formatting an array/object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66592859/jq-tsv-error-in-formatting-an-array-object), you required a line of dashes under the headers.

To automate the production of such a line, see
[How to format a JSON string as a table using jq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39139107/how-to-format-a-json-string-as-a-table-using-jq)

Comment: This is what I needed! Any why my display comes out like this: `"RELEASE\tINSTALLED\tLATEST\tDEPRECATED"
"test-app\t1.0.0\t2.0.0\tfalse"
"test-app2\t3.0.0\t3.5.0\tfalse"
` ?

Comment: That answers it! I also added `column -t` so it fit the columns properly

Comment: That's fine, but then it's no longer TSV :-)